# Elementary but intractable minimum

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $q$ be a power of a prime $p$ and $f\in\mathbb N^*$. For $n\in\mathbb N$, denote by $\overline n$ the residue of $n$ modulo $q^f$ in $\{0,\cdots, q^f-1\}$. Let $m,\alpha$ be elements of $\mathbb N^*$.
Can one show that the quantity
$$\sum_{i=mq^f}^{(m+\alpha)q^f-1}q^{l_i+\overline{i-l_i}}$$
admits one and only one minimum (that one will determine) when $(l_i)$ describes the set of sequences of distincts integers in $\{0,\cdots,\alpha q^m-1\}$?

Thanks in advance.